# spring receive emails without xml (using annotations only)

Tags: email, spring-boot, spring-integration

I need to periodically check about 30 mailboxes and want to do this with annotations only. I know how to do it with XML files, it looks like this:

```
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="ImapAdapter"
                              store-uri="imaps://${login}:${pass}@${host}:993/inbox"
                              channel="testReceiveEmailChannel"
                              should-delete-messages="false"
                              should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                              auto-startup="true"
                              java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="200"
                time-unit="SECONDS"
                task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor"/>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="testReceiveEmailChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator input-channel="testReceiveEmailChannel"
                       ref="testMailReceiverService"
                       method="receive"/>

<bean id="testMailReceiverService" class="com.myproject.email.EmailReceiverService">
    <property name="mailBox" value="${login}"/>
</bean>


<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>
```

I know that Spring 4+ have `@InboundChannelAdapter` but I dont know how to use it. Actually I am new in Spring, so any helps very appreciated!

Comment: This is a spring integration question not a spring or spring boot question. I have added the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking into the correct way - `@InboundChannelAdapter`. If you take a look to the [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15193) properly, you'll see something like this:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "testReceiveEmailChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "200000", taskExecutor = "asyncTaskExecutor"))
public MessageSource<javax.mail.Message> mailMessageSource(MailReceiver mailReceiver) {
    MailReceivingMessageSource mailReceivingMessageSource = new MailReceivingMessageSource(mailReceiver);
    // other setters here
    return mailReceivingMessageSource;
}
```

Where `MailReceiver` is something like this:

```
@Bean
public MailReceiver imapMailReceiver(@Value("imaps://${login}:${pass}@${host}:993/inbox") storeUrl) {
     ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(storeUrl);
        // other setters here
     return imapMailReceiver;
}
```

and so with other `@Bean`s for `MessageChannel` and `@ServiceActivator` for your `EmailReceiverService`.

Consider as a tool for Java Configuration the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl).

Comment: Thank for introduce :) What about `should-delete-messages="false"
                              should-mark-messages-as-read="true"` and other options?

Comment: Only now I try to implement this and have a trouble - I dont understand whats going on here. Can you explain _pipeline_ of message here? And give code for `@Beans for MessageChannel and @ServiceActivator` please?